# CakePHP: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp, listbox

I am a long time trying get a simple listmenu relation two tables with CakePHP, but it´s doesnt working. When I able the scaffold the list menu work (is it showing that relation is right?) But with my code not.

My url (localhost/forum/posts/add) is showing the error:

> Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\forum\app\Controller\PostsController.php

PostsController.php

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

public $name = 'Posts';

public function index() {

    $this->paginate = array('limit'=>3);
    $posts = $this->paginate('Post');
    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
public function getCategorias(){
    $categorias = $this->Post->Categotia->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'categoria')));
    $this->set(compact('categorias'));
}

public function add(){
    if($this->data){
        if($this->Post->save($this->data))
            $this->Session->setFlash('Post adicionado com sucesso');
    $this->data = array();  
    }
    self::getCategorias();
}

public function edit($id = null){
    if($this->data){
        if($this->Post->save($this->data))
                $this->Session->setFlash('Post editado com sucesso');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Posts','action'=>'index'));    
    }else{
        $this->data = $this->Post->read(null,$id);

    }
    self::getCategorias();
}

public function delete($id = null){
    if($id){
        if($this->Post->delete($id))
            $this->Session->setFlash('Post Excluido com sucesso');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Posts','action'=>'index')) ;

    }
}

public function view($id = null){
    if($id){
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
    }

}
```

}

My models are

Post.php :

```
class Post extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'Post';
    public $belongsTo = array('Categoria');
}
```

Categoria.php

```
class Categoria extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'Categoria';
    public $hasMany = array('Post');
}
```

Comment: My Table names are "posts" and "categorias"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've misspelled Categoria here:

> $categorias = $this->Post->**Categotia**->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'categoria')));

Answer (score 1):

```
 $this->Post->Categotia->find();
```

is wrong instead you can put

```
$this->Post->Categoria->find()
```